# C# how to find the flashdrive letter and use it in a directory/string

Tags: c#

I want to find the letter of a flash drive and create a file and put it in the flash drive that it found.

ex:

```
System.IO.File.Create(@"{Flash drive letter}\lol.txt");
```

Comment: That depends on how you define "Flash drive".  Look at `DriveInfo`.

Answer (score 2):

You should call DriveInfo.GetDrives() which returns an array of DriveInfo objects and then for each drive you should take care of the ones which DriveType == Removable. One initial code could be:

```
var removableDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(di => di.DriveType == DriveType.Removable);
foreach (var removableDrive in removableDrives){
     var removableDrivePath = removableDrive.Name;
     System.IO.File.Create(string.Format(@"{0}lol.txt", removableDrivePath));
}
```

Note that not all of the removable drives are in fact flash drives and also that there could be more than one removable drive in your computer.

Also, note that if the file (lol.txt in your case) already exists it's overwritten, if that's what you want, it's OK, if it's not what you want you should check [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f20d7x6t(v=vs.110).aspx) to create the file with another filemode and write the contents yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the DriveInfo example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

You are most likely looking for the removable device, if more than one you'll have to make some logic to choose...

Or you can enumerate the devices before they plug in the flash drive and then after and see the difference...